# change multiple div style when Hover on another Div using CSS

Tags: css, html

When I Hover on #main, Style of #box and #box2 want to change. But it is not working.

Html code is

```
<div id="main">Main</div>
<div id="box">Text</div>
<div id="box1" >Text1</div>
```

Css is

```
#main:hover + #box,#box1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/spk063/kVjrh/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
#main:hover + #box,
#main:hover ~ #box1 {
    /* CSS */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kVjrh/8/).

The problems you had, originally, were the two selectors:

```
#main:hover + #box,
#box1 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The first of which worked, unfortunately the comma separates entire selectors, it doesn't give a comma-separated list of descendants/siblings to be affected. So the `#box1` was *always* background-colored, rather than just on `:hover` of `#main`.

The combinators I've used are the adjacent-sibling combinator (`+`) and the general-sibling combinator (`~`), the latter of which will affect any later sibling of `#main` that has the given `id` of `box1`.

The second rule, written with `~` *could* be rewritten by specifying the exact sequence of elements using multiple (in this case two) adjacent-sibling combinators, to give:

```
#main:hover + #box,
#main:hover + #box + #box1 {
    /* CSS */
}
```

But this does become increasingly fragile over time, and maintenance becomes more trying when the HTML structure changes, or new elements are inserted between the relevant elements.

References:

- CSS Selectors.

Comment: `#main` is a sibling not a parent/grandparent

Comment: @DavidThomas help me with this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487499/change-multiple-div-style-when-hover-on-another-div-using-css

Answer (score 1):

probably cleaner to use a class and the general sibling selector (~):

HTML:

```
<div id="main">Main</div>
<div class="box">Text</div>
<div class="box" >Text1</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main:hover ~ .box {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Comment: Help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487499/change-multiple-div-style-when-hover-on-another-div-using-css