# Can CSS :hover selector affect multiple images in different DIV's

Tags: css, hover

I have a **lighter button image** surrounded by **lighter arrow images**. How can I **:hover** over these individual DIV'd images and cause the same button img AND both arrow img's to change to the darker img state?

Ex:

```
<div>[img]==></div> <div>[img]button</div> <div>[img]<==</div> LIGHTER IMG's
```

Swap with **:hover** to darker images

```
<div>[img]==></div> <div>[img]button</div> <div>[img]<==</div> **DARKER** IMG's
```

I hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: See 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17406149/change-multiple-div-style-when-hover-on-another-div-using-css

Comment: Only way I can think of in pure CSS is if they're contained in a single parent and you bind the `:hover` state to the parent.

Comment: In addition to binding `:hover` using a commen parent, you could also bind it to the `div`s and use sibling selectors to modify the images.